# How do I capture a jquery mobile slider value in parse.com?

Tags: jquery-mobile, parse-platform

I'm using jquery mobile to capture data and send to parse.com. The below code is the form being used.

I'm able to capture the BPsystolic and BPDiastolic data without issue. However I've noticed that only when the "Have you eaten in the last 2 hours?" slider is set to "YES" is the data being captured in the parse database.

My question is how do I capture the slider value when its set to "NO" ?

FORM CODE

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="healthform">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="eatentime">
                    Have you eaten in the last 2 hours?
                </label>
                <select name="toggleswitch1" id="eatentime" data-role="slider"
                data-mini="true">
                    <option value="off">
                        Yes
                    </option>
                    <option value="on">
                        No
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="BPsystolic">
                    Blood Pressure - Systolic (Top)
                </label>
                <input name="BPsystolic" id="BPsystolic" value="" type="number"
                data-mini="true">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="BPDiastolic">
                    Blood Pressure - Diastolic (Bottom)
                </label>
                <input name="BPDiastolic" id="BPDiastolic" value="" type="number"
                data-mini="true">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Upload Data">
        </form>
```

CODE TO SEND DATA TO PARSE

```
<script>

var SightingObject;
var db;

function errorCB(e) {
    //We should do something here - the database isn't technically required per se, but it should
    //work. 
    console.log("DB Error");
    console.dir(e);
}

function online() {
    //return false;
    return navigator.onLine;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    //initialize db
    db = window.openDatabase("sightingdb", "1.0", "Sighting Database", 200000);
    db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, initApp);

    function createDB(trans) {
        trans.executeSql("create table if not exists sighting(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,BPDiastolic,BPsystolic,eatentime)");
    }

});

/*
I'm run after the db is setup. 
*/
function initApp() {

    if(online()) {
        Parse.initialize("x", "x");
        SightingObject = Parse.Object.extend("SightingObject");

        //do we have existing objects in the db we can upload?
        db.transaction(function(trans) {
            trans.executeSql("select * from sighting", [], function(trans,result) {
                //do we have rows?
                if(result.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Ok, we need to push stuff up");
                    for(var i=0, len=result.rows.length; i<len; i++) {
                        var row = result.rows.item(i);

                        (function(row) {
                            //Parse will try to save everything, including ID, so make a quick new ob
                            var report = {};
                                report.BPDiastolic = row.BPDiastolic; 
                                report.BPsystolic = row.BPsystolic; 
                                report.eatentime = row.eatentime; 


                            saveToParse(report, function() { 
                                console.log("i need to delete row "+row.id);
                                db.transaction(function(trans) {
                                    trans.executeSql("delete from sighting where id = ?", [row.id]);
                                }, errorCB);
                            });
                        }(row));

                    }
                }
            },errorCB);
        }, errorCB, function() {
            console.log("Done uploading the old rows");
        });
    }

    $("#healthform").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
        gather the values - normally we'd do a bit of validation, but since UFO chasers
        are known for their rigorous and rational pursuit of science, this will not be necessary
        */
        var report = {};
            report.BPDiastolic = $("#BPDiastolic").val();
            report.BPsystolic = $("#BPsystolic").val();
            report.eatentime = $("#eatentime").val();

        console.log("To report: ",report);
        //ok, disable the form while submitting and show a loading gfx
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#loadingGraphic").show();

        if(online()) {
            console.log("I'm online, send to parse");
            saveToParse(report,resetForm);
        } else {
            console.log("I'm offline, save to WebSQL");
            db.transaction(function(trans) {
                trans.executeSql("insert into sighting(BPDiastolic,BPsystolic,eatentime) values(?,?,?)", [report.BPDiastolic,report.BPsystolic,report.eatentime]);
            }, errorCB, resetForm);
        }
    });

};

function saveToParse(ob,successCB) {
    var sightingObject = new SightingObject();
    sightingObject.save(ob, {
        success: function(object) {
            console.log("Saved to parse.");
            console.dir(object);
            successCB(object);
        },
        error: function(model, error) {
            console.log("Error!");
            console.dir(error);
        }
    });
}

//handles removing the disabled form stuff and loading gfx
function resetForm() {
    $("#BPDiastolic").val(""); 
    $("#BPsystolic").val(""); 
    $("#eatentime").val("");
    $("#sightForm").removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#loadingGraphic").hide();
    var status = $("#status");
    if(online()) {
        status.fadeIn().html("Your data has been saved!").fadeOut(4000);
    } else {
        status.fadeIn().html("Your data has been saved locally and will be uploaded next time you are online!").fadeOut(4000);
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with the code, more that the page was not refreshing correctly after the data was submitted. I added the jquery location.reload() to address this and it works fine now.